# A class of irrational numbers

Tags: number-theory

> Consider the function $f(x) = a^x +b^x – c^x$ with positive coprime integers $a < b < c$. When $f(2) > 0$, we have $f(t) = 0$ for some unique $t > 2$. Using FLT prove that $t$ cannot be rational.

Sidenote: An open (very difficult and very interesting) problem: Is $t$ algebraic or transcendental? (for $a = b$ we have $2a^t =c^t$ and $t$ must be transcendental according to the Gelfond–Schneider theorem).

Comment: Down voting as it is not clear what you are asking. If it is an open problem then it probably isn't suitable to ask here.

Comment: I ask for t must be irrational. It is clearly expressed.

Comment: The open problem is just notified

Comment: So, the first block of text is your question, and the second block only an interesting comment? If that is the case, you really should make that more obvious.

Comment: I thought to say "open" enough to understand that this was not the question (for this the uppercase letters)

Comment: I proposed an edit to make it clearer. Remember that the only real question in your post is the open problem, which might confuse readers.

Comment: http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/cmj_ftp/CMJ/May%202010/3%20Articles/1%20Morgan/Morgan9_5_09.pdf

Comment: Thanks again. When I am going to write "Note off the question" I saw your better English with "Sidenote", a word I come to learn.

Comment: I don't agree. I ask for t cannot be a rational non integer.

Comment: Believe me, please, Jack Yoon.I did not know of that paper. Thank you.

Comment: FYI Luis, if you add a '@' in front of the name of the user you want to reach, the user in question will get notified. Otherwise, he/she must return and find your comment more or less by accident.

Comment: @Jack Yoon, note that all the infinite examples of the paper are trivial solutions which derive from a+b=c and from the pytagorean triples, My condition f(2) positive discards these examples.

Comment: Of course. The relevant part is in the next section, namely lemma 3 and proposition 4.

Comment: @Jack Yoon, I will see the lemma 3. However, see  my answer to the question, please

Comment: @Jack Yoon. Nothing to deny my answer in your paper.

Comment: I am very confused. The fact that $t$ has to be rational is true and there is no doubt about it. You seem to have wanted a proof which I gave a reference.

Comment: @Jack Yoon. Absolutely right what you say but your examples doesn't satisfy the condition f(2) > 0.

Comment: It immediately implies it. Stronger statement in fact.

Comment: Also I have followed your posts and you seem to be posting question which you know the answer to. This is NOT the point of the website!

Comment: A lapsus? do you want to say actually the contrary of  "posting question which you know the answer to"?

Comment: @JackYoon Actually, it's [encouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) to answer your own questions, even when you know the answer at the time of posting. That said, it should be done with [some care](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13095/is-it-not-allowed-to-answer-ones-own-question/13096#13096).

Comment: If I have to post just questions I don’t know the answer tomorrow I’ll post Riemann Hypothesis.

Comment: @Jack Yoon. Take the famous triple (3,4,5) so f(x) = (3^2n)^x + (4^2n)^x – (5^2n)^x has infinitely many obvious (and trivial) rational solutions. But f(2) < 0. Where is the stronger fact you say?

Comment: By the way, I remember the “proof” of a psychopathic  engineer at Venezuela: “If (x,y,z) is a solution then (mx,my,mz) is also a solution for all m. Then by Faltings’s theorem, FLT is proved”.

Answer (score 0):

When a, b, c are m-powers one has for f(n/m)= f(n) which can be zero zero just for n = 1 or 2 by FLT but in this case f(2) < 0 what denies our condition f(2) > 0. Let now a, b and c be not m-powers 
simultaneously and our t = n/d be rational non integer. This gives the three possibilities of the shape N^t + M =0, N^t + M^t + P = 0 and N^t + M^t + R^t = 0 where the rational integers M, N R with exponents become irrational (because they are supposed not d-powers). In the three cases we have the impossibility by Q-linear independence (ma^t + nb^t + sc^t = 0 with m, n, s rational imply m = n = s = 0 in the third case and similarly with the other two cases).Therefore t cannot be rational.

Answer (score 0):

Proposition 4 of the link I posted says Fermat's theorem holds for rational exponents greater than 2. That is to say rational solution to $$x^n+y^n=z^n$$ exists if and only if $n=1/m$ or $n=2/m$ for some none zero integer $m$.

I said that proposition 4 is a stronger statement (which you gave a 'counterexample'). Well technically what I said isn't true I guess. But it very obviously implies it. Ie if in the above setting $t>2$, for contradiction we assume $t$ is rational. Then as $(a,b,c)$ is a rational solution to $$x^t+y^t=z^t$$ and by proposition $4$ this means $t$ is either $1/m$ or $2/m$ for some positive integer $m$.(negative integer is obviously ruled out also as $t>0$) But this is impossible as $1/m<2/m \leq2$ for all $m\in \mathbb{Z}_+$. Hence $t$ cannot be rational.

Comment: Hi Jack Yoon, I read your link and I realize you are right really however it is not in the line I wanted to ask in my question (your answer something  seems to me proving  using the desired result). I was really touched by the last sentence of the summary: “It is apparently unknown whether E contains any algebraic irrationals”. This is my very difficult problem indeed but I have posted it as a simple sidenote (I was wrong to believe that no one else had seen this problem). Regards.